# Generate a list of citations that can be safely combined

Tags: bibtex, citing, achemso

So, I've got some really ugly citations superscripts, the worst being " 11,20,80,81,83,85,90,91", but I was reading the `achemso` manual and noticed you can use citation groups, which would help clean some of these up. However, I often reference citations later in a document. Is there a way to get a list of citations that are safe to group? (For example, ones that are only cited once, or are always cited together?)

Here is an example of what will happen if I try to add citations without knowing which are safe to group:

```
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage{mciteplus}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Thuery2015,
  author = "P. Thu\'{e}ry",
  year = "2015",
  howpublished = "CCDC 1063730: Experimental Crystal Structure Determination",
  DOI = "10.5517/cc14pwwl"
}
@article{Kerr2011,
author = {Kerr, Andrew T. and Cahill, Christopher L.},
journal = {Cryst. Growth Des.},
number = {12},
pages = {5634--5641},
volume = {11},
year = {2011}
}
@article{Thuery2007,
author = {Thu{\'{e}}ry, Pierre},
journal = {Acta Crystallogr. Sect.~C~Cryst. Struct. Commun.},
month = {feb},
number = {2},
pages = {m54--m56},
volume = {63},
year = {2007}
}
@misc{Ephritikhine2013a,
  author = "G. Siffredi and  J. C. Berthet and P. Thu\'{e}ry and M. Ephritikhine",
  year = "2013",
  howpublished = "CCDC 958352: Experimental Crystal Structure Determination",
  DOI = "10.5517/cc1157l1"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Multiple citations to be combined into a list\cite{Kerr2011} can be given as a single citation.\cite{Thuery2015,*Kerr2011}  
This\cite{Thuery2015} uses the \textsf{mciteplus} package\cite{Thuery2015,*Ephritikhine2013a,*Kerr2011,*Thuery2007}.
Citations other than the first of the list should be indicated with a star. 
Individual references can be referred to using \texttt{\textbackslash mciteSubRef}: 
``ref.~\mciteSubRef{Ephritikhine2013a}''.\mciteSubRef{Ephritikhine2013a}
\end{document}
```